# PHP- Todo object oriented program

Tags: php, class

I have a todo program in php but i keep on getting this errors(
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function completed() on null in C:\wamp64\www\classes.php on line 38

Call to a member function completed() on null  on line 38
),, So this program has tasks  that I  can set/create , these tasks can be set to completed(which one the property can access) individually,  for example if a can set some of those task or a task to completed that task or those task among the other task which are not set to completed are going to be striked through  and executed inform of a listing on the browser all together. can anyone assisst??

```
<?PHP

    Class main{
     
    public $completed=false;     
    public $name;
    
    function set_task($desc){
                
            $this->name=$desc;
    
       } 
    function get_task(){
             return $this->name;   
    
       }
       
     public function completed(){
    
        if($this->completed==false){
    
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        } 
    
    } 
    } 
    
    $task=new main();
    
     $t1=$task->`set_task`("Go to the store");
     $t2=$task->`set_task`("Do homework");
     $t3=$task->`set_task`("Take a run");
    
    $Tasks=[];
    
    $t1->completed();
    
    array_push($Tasks,$t1);
    array_push($Tasks,$t2);
    array_push($Tasks,$t3);
    
    
    foreach($Tasks as $task){
            
    if($task->completed()){
     
     print_r("<strike>$task</strike>");
    }
    else{
    
     `print_r`($task);   
    
    }
    
    }
    
    
    
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$t1 returns a void whilst you would have to create a new object in order to get $t1 as an object.
thus, you can theoretically run

```
$task->completed();
```

but I think this is not your intention. So I guess you would need to create 3 new objects.